# Set different size for each columns in Reportlab

Tags: python, django, reportlab

I am using Reportlab in python. Now I am trying to customize each column width. Because some of the columns need small width rather than other columns. Is there any way to make each column customizable?

[image: Exported PDF file]

Currently from the picture, I would like to increase the width of the Partname column width and set small width for tax, Style p, etc.

views.py

```
columns = [
        {'title': 'Part No', 'field': 'partno'},
        {'title': 'Part Name', 'field': 'partname'},
        {'title': 'Style P', 'field': 'style'},
        {'title': 'Standard P', 'field': 'standardpack'},
        {'title': 'Unit Per Car', 'field': 'unit'},
        {'title': 'Quantity PCS', 'field': 'quantity'},
        {'title': 'Tax', 'field': 'tax'},
        {'title': 'Unit Price', 'field': 'price'},
        {'title': 'Amount', 'field': 'amount'},
    ]

    table_data = [[col['title'] for col in columns]]
    
        table_row = [str(tr.part.partno),tr.part.partname,
                     tr.part.stylepack, tr.part.standardpack,tr.part.unit, tr.quantity, tr.part.tax, tr.part.price, tr.amount]
        table_data.append(table_row)

    table = Table(table_data, repeatRows=1, colWidths=[150,150])
    table.setStyle(TableStyle([
        ('BOX', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.20, colors.dimgrey),
        ('FONT', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 'Helvetica-Bold'),
        ('INNERGRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.1, colors.black),     
        ('ALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'CENTER'),
        ('FONTSIZE', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 10),      
    ]))
    elements.append(table)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply like this :

```
from reportlab.lib.units import inch

 colWidths=(1.2*inch, 1.2*inch, 2.4*inch, 1.2*inch, 1.2*inch, 1.2*inch, 1.2*inch, 1.2*inch)
```

Comment: This will apply for each column, but I want to apply an example for only the Partname column is 2.4 inch, but the rest of the column will be lower than 2.4

Comment: Don't you can apply like this :  colWidths=(1.2*inch, 1.2*inch, 2.4*inch, 1.2*inch, 1.2*inch, 1.2*inch, 1.2*inch, 1.2*inch)